# Scroll the whole dialog instead of just its content

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview, android-alertdialog

Currently I use a ScrollView to be able to scroll my dialog's content down. But I find it a bit ugly and I want to do it another way: Is there a way that the whole dialog can scroll vertically? Something like this:

[image: what I'm searching for]

The slider on the right is optional, this is just to show the scrolling. Also note that I made this picture, there is no code associated with it.

The reason I want to do this is that it's simpler than making two different layout for each orientation. It also offers more interactable space compared with a dialog with locked title bar at the top, locked buttons at the bottom and scrolling content. Consider this:

[image: interactable area]

What would be the best way to make this scrolling dialog? Do you know any other solution to solve the same problem, like scrolling the title and buttons with the rest of the content maybe...?

Comment: please post your code and xml

Comment: I don't have any. This is a basic dialog / dialog activity. See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: set gravity of alert dialog to CENTER with the width and height non static then no need to scroll the dialog.